# How to write a case statement with date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to return the Quarter based on the a datetime value.

I'm getting an error for the below script:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

```
DECLARE @d AS DATETIME
SET @d = GETDATE()

SELECT CASE 
        WHEN @d BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-03-31' THEN 'Q1'
        WHEN @d BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-06-31' THEN 'Q2'
        WHEN @d BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-09-31' THEN 'Q3'
        WHEN @d BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2018-12-31' THEN 'Q4'
        ELSE 'Q?'
        END
```

It seems to work fine with a single "WHEN" clause, but with 4 it gives an error.

What is the reason?

Comment: And what you will do next year?  i think it's better to use builed in method so you dont need to rewrite the query for every year. Please refer to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because June and September only have 30 days, but you're asking for their 31st day.

Also, your last when statement is a year off.

Answer (score 3):

you have a built-in method for that:

```
SELECT DATEPART(QUARTER, @d)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such date as 2017-06-31. It should be 2017-06-30.